# Search for Max Date and return max date item along with other fields for that record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables:

- WorkOrder that contains all of the Work Orders that have been done on MaintItems, (A MaintItem will occur multiple times in the WorkOrder Table)
- MaintItems that contains a list of Unique MaintItems,
- LastOccu to store the Last Occurrence details from the WorkOrder table of the MaintItem.

To identify the last date that a MaintItem was performed and to populate the LastOccu table with the MaxDate and MaintItem works correctly. The Problem that I have is when I want to update the lastOccu table with the additional WorkOrder Number field, the query then returns all WorkOrders for that MaintItem.

> WorkOrder table example:
>
> ```
> WorkOrder MaintItem   RefDate     Reading
> 1         101         2018/01/30  200
> 2         103         2018/02/03  1200
> 3         101         2018/02/04  230
> ```

LastOccu table result required:

```
MaintItem MaxDate    WONumber Reading
101       2018/01/30 3        230
103       2018/02/03 2        1200
```

The Query that I need help with as follows:

```
INSERT INTO LastOccu ( MaintItem, MaxDate, WONumber, ReadingNo )
SELECT MD.MaintItem, MD.MaxRefDate, MD.WONumber, MD.ReadingNo
FROM 
(SELECT MI.MaintItem, MAX(WO.RefDate) AS MaxRefDate, WO.WONumber,
WO.ReadingNo FROM MaintItem AS MI INNER JOIN WorkOrder AS WO ON 
MI.MaintItem = WO.MaintItem WHERE WO.RefDate is not null GROUP BY
MI.MaintItem, WO.WONumber, WO.ReadingNo)  AS MD;
```

***Also note that I'm using MS Access***

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've changed the tag to denote ms-access not SQL Server, if there is a SQL Server element in this please re-add it with some details about which part specifically is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the necessity to join with MaintItem table. Each workorder should already have a corresponding MaintItem entry, no? If not, then join (is that WorkOrder or WONumber I couldn't understand).

```
INSERT INTO LastOccu(MaintItem, MaxDate, WONumber, ReadingNo)
SELECT wo.MaintItem, wo.RefDate, wo.Workorder, wo.ReadingNo
FROM WorkOrder wo
     INNER JOIN(
               SELECT MaintItem, MAX(RefDate) AS MaxRefDate
               FROM WorkOrder
               WHERE RefDate IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY MaintItem
               ) AS MD ON wo.MaintItem=MD.MaintItem
                      AND wo.RefDate=MD.MaxRefDate;
```

Note: Oops, I missed you changed tag from sql server to MSAccess. That doesn't support ANSI SQL but at least should support this kind of simple ones I assume, so not deleting. (Your sample output doesn't seem to be right, if that is what could be the logic?).

EDIT:

```
INSERT INTO LastOccu(MaintItem, MaxDate, WONumber, ReadingNo)
SELECT wo.MaintItem, wo.RefDate, wo.Workorder, wo.ReadingNo
FROM WorkOrder wo
     INNER JOIN(
               SELECT MaintItem, MAX(RefDate) AS MaxRefDate
               FROM WorkOrder
               WHERE RefDate IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY MaintItem
               ) AS MD ON wo.MaintItem=MD.MaintItem
                      AND wo.RefDate=MD.MaxRefDate
    where MaintItem in (Select MaintItem from MaintItem);
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. The reason for the join on the MaintItem table is because the WorkOrder table would reference deleted MaintItems. So I Only want the MaintItems from the WorkOrder Table that have a corresponding MaintItem in the MaintItem table....

Comment: That doesn't seem to be right from an integrity point. But then you can add it with a join or EXISTS (or IN query). I will add and edited version.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this uses a correlated subquery:

```
INSERT INTO LastOccu ( MaintItem, MaxDate, WONumber, ReadingNo )
    SELECT MD.MaintItem, MD.MaxRefDate, MD.WONumber, MD.ReadingNo
    FROM WorkOrder as wo INNER JOIN
         MaintItem as mi
         ON mi.MaintItem = wo.MaintItem
    WHERE wo.RefDate = (SELECT MAX(wo2.RefDate)
                        FROM WorkOrder as wo2
                        WHERE wo2.MaintItem = wo.MaintItem
                       );
```

The filtering on `NULL` is not important, because `NULL` values will not pass the filter.